# Address standarization using C# dictionary data or table sql server data?

Tags: c#, sql-server, dictionary

I'm developing an application for address standardization in c# using form (desktop application) and sql server 2005. It work as follow:

My model in SQL:

```
---------------------|   
Table correctAddress | 
---------------------| 
correctAddressId pk  | 
correctAddress       | 
---------------------| 

-------------------|
Table wrongAddress |
-------------------|
wrongAddressId pk  |
wrongAddress       |
correctAddressId fk|
-------------------|

-------------------------|
Table standardizeAddress |
-------------------------|
standardizeAddressId  pk |
streetName               |
-------------------------|
```

> CorrectAddress: 70.000 records
>   wrongAddress: 900.000 records
>   standardizeAddress: maybe 1 or 1.000.000 records.

And my query to get and change "streetName" to "correctAddress" is:

```
SELECT s.standardizeAddressId, s.streetName, c.correctAddress
  FROM correctAddress  c 
       INNER JOIN wrongAddress        w ON c.correctAddressId = w.correctAddressId 
       INNER JOIN standardizeAddress  s ON w.wrongAddress = s.streetName
```

This query work, but when I've million or thounsand of `standardizeAddress` records, it take so much time (20 minutes).

So, looking for a best solution, I saw c# `Dictionary` as data structure. 
My question is if Could I do the same work using c# `Dictionary`? putting all `correctAddress` and `wrongAddress` in a c# dictionary for get  correctAddress?

It work better? or There is another best option? 
I'm thinking something like that using dictionary:

```
Public correctAddress As Dictionary(Of String, String) = New Dictionary(Of String, String)

Public Sub New()
        With directionals
            .Add("Riverside Drive", "Rvrsid Drve")
            .Add("Union Street", "Unon Strt")
            .Add("Grand Avenue", "Grnd Avene")
-- and so on until 900.000 records!
End With
```

Tanks for your comments!

Comment: Does your server have appropriate indexes? I wouldn't expect an inner join on appropriate keys to take very long - a million records really isn't that many...

Comment: Add non-unique indexes on standardizeAddress.streetName and w.wrongAddress - should fly in comparison to any (non-specialist) coding.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact that is hard to say where is actual bottleneck in your case, just by reading the post, if you think about handling the data in memory, you  can use 
[DataSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset(v=vs.110).aspx) (a collection of [DataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx)). You can query them with SQL in memory as well.